# How do I make the promo image and text link to my home page on my Drupal page?

Tags: image, drupal, hyperlink

I'm new at this and do not have a lot of experience with computers in general.

On the left, my site has a picture and some text underneath it. It is called "promo" or "teaser". Right now, if I click on it, it goes to a different page (www.sitename.com/promo). I want it to go to my homepage (www.sitename.com/home). 
When I try to edit the template, I can't find where to change the address to which it links.

If you can give any tips or advice, please do so!

Thank you! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm It's a "promo" block that displays a picture with text underneath it on the left sidebar, on every page. So through your questions, Grezly, I'm perceiving that I must somehow make the home page show up as a block with a "teaser" underneath on every page?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you exactly want to do for me.

But take a look at the blocks that are created and used, also the templates itself you have to look through.

Maybe you did use some blocks/templates on different sections?
Is it possible to give a little bit more information?

**Edit:**
Can It also be a module that you installed?